# When using aggregation to get the taxonomy count, how can I exclude the currently displayed term?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Based on [these instructions](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/01/20/drupal-7-get-number-of-nodes-of-taxonomy-term-in-views/) I created a view that shows the number of nodes that contain taxonomy terms from a given vocabulary.

This view is displayed as a content pane in Panels on the taxonomy page with the Contextual Filter `Taxonomy term: Parent term` (when the filter is not available, provide a `Fixed value` of `0`).  This gives me a list of all terms of the same level (the sibling terms), which is what I want.  However, I don't want to show the term for the currently selected page, as that is already being displayed in Panels.

How can I exclude the term for the given page?

Example:

On the "Apples" taxonomy page:

- Apples (7)
- Oranges (5)
- Pears (3)

-> I don't want to show the result for "Apples."